# Facebook Graph API Error - No redirect uri

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, request

I'm throughly stumped. I can run this simple GET request in postman and have no issue, but when making it from the rails api running locally it fails with this error. I have tried using my localhost, ipadress and in this latest attempt just the route and still having an issue.

Here is the [documatation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens) on this request

The Error

```
{ "error":
   { 
     "message": "Missing redirect_uri parameter.",
     "type":"OAuthException",
     "code":191,
     "fbtrace_id":"BjAByCFGkQL"
   }
}
```

The Request

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=123456789&client_secret=123456789&redirect_uri=/my_auth_callback&grant_type=client_credentials

Comment: The redirect URI needs to be an absolute URL. And btw., if you read that section of the documentation you linked to to the end - you don’t need to make an extra API call to get an app access token, app id and secret can be used for that directly.

Comment: @CBroe that is good to know and will try this tonight!

Comment: @CBroe The issue ended up being there was an issue with ruby's get request and switched that and it started working, but if you want to put an answer about the shorter way to make that same request I would happily upvote that as it saves me a call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect URI needs to be an absolute URL.

And btw., you don’t need to make an extra API call to get an app access token, app id and secret can be used for that directly:

```
app_id|app_secret
```

is always a valid app access token.

Comment: Thanks for the help! For anyone running into the same issue please review your get request, but this was a more succinct way to make the request